# How to make Abilities make sense mechanically (and pseudoscientifically)?

Tags: super-powers

I'm writing a fan spin-off of Uru-chan's [*unOrdinary*](https://www.webtoons.com/en/super-hero/unordinary/list?title_no=679), but there is unfortunately not much in the wiki about abilities and aura. Below is the *unOrdinary* definition of Ability and Aura mechanics with my own :

> Abilities are powers that people are born with, though the manifestation time differs per person; few individuals displayed their abilities at birth, but most discover their abilities when they are 5 or 6 years old. Hereditary abilities are passed from the parent/s to the offspring, though parents without abilities can have a child with abilities, and children can sometimes possess Abilities that are different from their parents Abilities. Whenever an Ability is used, it usually gives off an Aura in the user's hair or eye color. It flows through Aura Channels which regulate he flow of Aura through the body. A stronger flow of Aura naturally results in a stronger ability. Normally, the aura flow cannot be altered by consciously, though Meta Abilities allow the user direct control to their Aura Channels.

According to the feedback from [an older post of mine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/218033/how-do-i-change-this-guys-ability-so-he-isnt-so-powerful), which was closed for being  I need to define "some more details about the Abilities and their underlying mechanics" (@Otkin). I looked at [this post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened) and saw that my question was well within the lines of an on-topic question. That said, what can I do to improve the system of Abilities and Aura?

Comment: Your older question is way better and better articulated.  I am sorry to report that I accidentally retracted my reopen vote because I got too clicky.   Closers got to vote to close because that is n their nature but I think that will get reopened.   It is good.

Comment: For the record, I do not think that your question is off-topic or too story-based. I voted to keep it open and I voted to reopen it. My only problem is that I do not have a good understanding of Abilities and their inner workings.

Comment: Yes, talent has a strong hereditary component. For example, look up how many mathematicians, physicists, painters and other exceptional people were produced by the [Bernoulli family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_family) or the [Curie family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_family). But I don't know about auras.

Comment: For the other record, I voted to put on hold as "needs details and clarity" so details could be added in response to comments. A number of edits clearing things up were made ... and for yet another record, it's not turned up in the reopen queue yet, else I should have voted to reopen before now - I just have.

Answer (score 1):

From your other question :

> A boy with a troubled past, Grey is naturally a good kid, but has a tendency to violence, and swears to destroy the system of hierarchy that places the strongest at the top of the social food chain, leaving the weak helpless and at the mercy of the higher tiers. He charades as a cripple (though his closest group of friends know about his power, and try to help him with his past), but is actually one of the strongest in his school. His Ability, Aura Manipulation, allows him to detect, manipulate and copy Auras, allowing him to observe the Aura Flow in other power users, copy their Abilities, and combine them in order to produce devastating results (e.g., copying and combining Fire and Wind produces Firenado, not a separate Ability but a combination of the two; some Abilities failed to combine, so not all abilities are compatible). The only limitations so far is that he can copy up to 4 abilities, and he can only use them for a short time period.

> Grey has successfully dethroned the Houses (group of "elite" students at a school) of both New Bostin, Southport and Wellington High, and there is seemingly no end to his power. What are some possible nerfs that can be implemented to his power?

These are a few obvious nerfs --

- While Grey can copy Auras, he might not be able to do much about his own Aura Flow (ability strength). He can copy a *hellfire*, but there might be many people who can throw a stronger *hellfire*.
- Ohm's Law. If Grey's Aura Flow is fixed, copying and merging abilities might divide Grey's aura flow by the number of abilities Grey is copying. This is like a voltage or current divider in an electrical circuit. So, Grey's Fire+Wind *Firenado* is half the strength of Grey's *Hellfire*.

  - *Aura Manipulation* might count towards this total, so *Hellfire* is at 1:2 strength, and *Firenado* is at 1:3 strength.
- Power Law. In electronics, $P = I^2 R$. Another optional nerf would be that Grey's time-to-exhaustion goes down exponentially with the # of abilties he's copying. Grey may only be able to use *Aura Manipulation* + *Hellfire* for $1:2^2$ = ${1 \over 4}^{th}$ the time of someone who's natural ability is *Hellfire* alone.
- Skill. Grey is copying abilities that others have been practicing and mastering their whole lives. Yes, Grey can copy *Invisibility* or *Stoneskin*, but maybe he's not really good at it, leaving parts visible or exposed to injury.
- Pacing. May turn out that mastering an Ability isn't merely throwing a damaging *Hellfire* or an impressive *Invisibility*. People might not even think of it, but over time they are learning endurance and mastering the unexpected skill of pacing their Aura Flow in this way. Grey might also have to master this pacing. And, this art might be as different for each Ability as mastering marathon running is to pacing yourself appropriately for swimming the English Channel, or a Polar Bear endurance competition.